# Nexus 7 Support for Android Application Manifest Assembly

Tags: android, manifest, google-play, nexus-7

I have an Android Application that has the AndroidManifest.xml listed below.  After uploading to Google Play, the Nexus 7 is listed as an UNSUPPORTED device and I am trying to figure out why.  Of course Google Play doesn't tell you why or what permission or use of the manifest is restricting it from being supported.  Any ideas of which part of the code below is causing the Nexus 7 to be listed as unsupported?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxx.xxxx.applet"
    android:versionCode="x"
    android:versionName="x.x" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

    <application
        android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >

        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_list" />
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

It comes as a surprise to many because the Nexus 7 does have a front facing camera, but it seems that it does not count for the purposes of this particular permission.

Comment: To overcome this, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>`. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html

Comment: SUCCESS!! Thank you.  Additionally, Google Play now shows 40 more available devices.  Apologize if I could have found this in another thread but thanks for the quick and correct response

Comment: @CommonsWare When I tried to run this https://github.com/pplante/zxing-android in Nexus 7  Shows dialog " Sorry the android camera encounters a problem, you may needs to restart the device !" but works fine on mobiles tried with `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>` not worked !

Comment: @Subra: That has nothing to do with this question (related to Play Store listings), and you already filed an issue with the project related to your crash: https://github.com/pplante/zxing-android/issues/2

Comment: @user1607521 I'm curious which devices those are - but I'd guess Google Play doesn't tell you that in a convenient way either...

Comment: CommonsWare's solution worked for me.  Be mindful that **it may take a few hours for the change to become apparent through the Play store**.