# Android Mediarecorder using front facing camera

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

I am developing an app that is supposed to record videos using the front facing camera. It is working now using the back camera. When I tried to change the cameraID to select the profile of the front facing camera as mentioned in

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681703/android-cant-record-video-with-front-facing-camera-mediarecorder-start-failed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

actually nothing happens and still the back camera is used.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public static MediaRecorder recorder;
    public static SurfaceHolder holder;
    public static SurfaceView cameraView;
    boolean recording = false;
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        if(checkPermission()) {
            initRecorder();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
            holder = cameraView.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            cameraView.setClickable(true);
            cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            requestPermission();
            initRecorder();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
            holder = cameraView.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            cameraView.setClickable(true);
            cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    private  int getCamID() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx<cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                return camIdx;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        int camID = getCamID();
        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(camID,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);

        //get the time stamp
        String timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
        //remove the seconds part
        timestamp = timestamp.substring(0, timestamp.length()-6).replaceAll(":","");
        //append file name to the time stamp
        String filestamp =  timestamp;
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                filestamp +".mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
            recorder.release();
            // Let's initRecorder so we can record again

        } else {
            initRecorder();
            prepareRecorder();
            recording = true;
            recorder.start();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        prepareRecorder();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        finish();
    }



    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
                String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO,CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }


    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                RECORD_AUDIO);
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                CAMERA);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.android.mediarecorder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
      <activity
            android:name="com.example.amokh.videorecorder02.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaRecorder defines [setCamera()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setcamera) method which is [easy to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503007/192373), but was deprecated in API 21 (because it refers to the old Camera API). For API 21+, it's preferable to open the camera with [camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) and use `setVideoSource(SURFACE)`, as shown in the official [camera2video sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L583).

Comment: Thank you for help. Then how to select the front camera? or using surface as a source does that automatically?

Comment: As you can see the in the linked example, you connect the surface to camera device, which you open with any parameters as you wish.