# My App isn't Compatible with Nexus 7 on Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, nexus-7, android-compatibility

Hii i have submitted an app to playstore but it isn't compatible with Nexus here is my Manifest 
   My App is on List of supported Devices in the Google Play 
    [image]

and when i check the same in the nexus device it is not at all visible on Search

[image]

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
     /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"  />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY"  />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:required="false" />
```

I Have Searched in google and did necessary Modifications to Manifest still i don't know why my app isn't compatible with nexus 7

please help me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: did u try uncommenting the upper part?

Comment: Tried But Didn't work same msg Your Device isn't compatible with this version

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

and

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>
```

and may be remove the camera permission.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html) reads:

> Be aware of which system features that you declare (or imply) are
>   required to run your application or the Play Store will not make your
>   application available to Nexus 7 users. Always declare hardware
>   features that aren't critical to your app as required="false" then
>   detect at runtime if the feature is present and progressively enhance
>   functionality

Comment: Already I Have Specified Them in My Manifest File but iam geting same Your Device isn't compatible with this version

Comment: did you remove the camera permission?

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't seem to be related to your listing on the app store. According to the console your application is compatible with the Nexus 7.

The first thing I would suggest is [checking appt](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing).

Next, my guess is that either the Play Store hasn't updated the listing yet or your device is not identifying itself appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

They make sure that a camera and a flashlight are present on the device.

You've already mentioned :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
android:protectionLevel="normal"
android:required="false" />
```

This should be enough. The permissions negate the `android:required="false"` feature and hence the Nexus 7 is excluded.

So, just remove the two permissions and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the flashlight permission twice. And the first time you aren't specifying that it is not required.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

This is probably conflicting with the second declaration.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:required="false" />
```

Try removing the first one and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

- uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"  android:targetSdkVersion="19" in manifest

---

Answer (score 0):

You should define the support screens feature in your manifest as below which will allow to support nexus 7:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [Nexus 7 Support for Android Application Manifest Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010383/nexus-7-support-for-android-application-manifest-assembly)

Nexus 7 cannot support `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`.

Comment: i Have Alredy Added the line <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try including the following:

```
<compatible-screens>
....
    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745425/348154%20a) based on [this workaround](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34076).

Answer (score 0):

As update button is shown in front of app, and also caution is given. So if you are able to update app then it could be some bug in Play Store app.  or try removing

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add this line also since you are using READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Comment: "Add this line" -- which line?

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

It solved my issue for nexus 7

Comment: I see. It looks like that line didn't show up in your post. Try putting it inside a pair of backticks ` or indent it four spaces to create a code block.